# Converting lines into points based on values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, lines-to-points

I have some lines of symbols. I want to vary the number of symbols based on a value.

I working on households I don't know the street where the are living but not exactly their address. For one household the point should be located a the middle of the polyline / line.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your line symbology or add a second style, using cmarker line`$length/"column holding your numbers"`.

Choose `interval` (topmost bulletpoint), change the spacing to `map units`, then hit the rectangle to the right of the option in order to access data defined override using the option `edit` in the drop down menu. Enter `$length/"column holding your numbers"` ad value. This will create a marker symbol every x meter along your line, where x is its length divided by the number you mentioned.

The style still begins at the starting point of the line, so you need to move the first marker along the line. Again, choose `map units` and access data defined override. Here you enter `$length/"column holding your numbers"/2` - this will move your first marker x/2 m along the line, with x being the same as above.

For orientation & illustration of the style, check the attached screenshot.

[image]